# How can I override RouteOptions.LowercaseUrls on a per-action basis?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my ASP.NET Core 2.1 web-application I have this in my Startup method:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>( o =>
{
    o.LowercaseUrls = true;
} );
```

For the uninitiated, this setting causes `UrlHelper` to render all path components (but not querystring items) in lowercase.

For example, given this Controller and Action:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [Route("/FOO/bAR/{baz}")]
    public IActionResult Bar( [FromRoute] String baz, [FromQuery] String qux )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And given this Razor expression:

```
@Url.Action( action: nameof(FooController.Bar), new { baz = "Ab", qux = "Ab" } )
```

With `o.LowercaseUrls = false` then this will be rendered:

```
/FOO/bAR/Ab?qux=Ab
```

With `o.LowercaseUrls = true` then this will be rendered:

```
/foo/bar/ab?qux=Ab
```

Using `LowercaseUrls = true` is fine (even preferred!) for 90% of my Actions, but for a handful of URLs it's important that the case of the route parameters are preserved (in particular, when a route parameter is a Base64-encoded or Linux filename where case-sensitivity is important).

Currently the only workaround is to convert them to querystring parameters instead of route parameters, but that's not ideal.

Is there any way I can annotate an Action with something like `[PreserveRouteParameterCasing]` or similar?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I'm looking to do the exact same thing

Comment: @b9bram Indirectly. I currently have `LowercaseUrls = false`. Instead I have a T4 script that searches my entire project for `[Route]` attributes and generates a new class at compile-time that renders routes correctly. This also means I have strongly-typed action parameters (no more anonymous-classes for route and querystring parameters!).